# How to disable OpenGL threaded optimization on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, graphics-card, graphics, opengl

How can I do the equivalent of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1jlR.jpg) on my 2009 Mac Mini (Mac OS X Lion):